# Schema for element with Attributes and Child nodes

Tags: xml, xsd

I am trying to write xsd type schema for an element that has a custom type to include addition attributes to extend a base type. I am running into trouble getting the syntax right.

```
<xs:element name="graphs">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="graph" 
                  minOccurs="1"
                  maxOccurs="unbounded"
                  type="graphType">
        <!-- child elements -->
      </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:complexType name="graphType">
<xs:simpleContent>
  <xs:extension base="xs:string">
    <xs:attribute name="title" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:attribute name="type" type="xs:string"/>
  </xs:extension>
</xs:simpleContent>
</xs:complexType>
```

I thought this would be something very common, but having read many tuts and forums, I cant seem to find an answer that works for me.

*Edit: Actually I don't want the parent node (graph) to contain string data, only xml..*

Answer (score 2):

I have come up with this..

```
<xs:element name="graphs">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="graph" 
                  minOccurs="1"
                  maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="sequence" type="sequenceType"/>
          </xs:sequence>
          <xs:attribute name="title" type="xs:string"/>
          <xs:attribute name="type" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:complexType name="sequenceType">
    <xs:simpleContent>
      <xs:extension base="xs:string">
        <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string"/>
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:simpleContent>
</xs:complexType>
```

I think it syntactically valid. Does it seem correct?